# Unable to save order in foreach

Tags: magento2, orders

Here is my code i just want to update order column that are in collection in foreach i have tried model and modelfactory both to save but it sets Queued column but unable to save it anyone kindly help is a great help.

```
public function execute()
        {
        //all order collection
        $collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('queued',['in' => 0]);
        $ordercollection = $collection->getData();

        foreach ($ordercollection as $key=>$order) {
           
            try {
                //$this->saveOrderqueued($order['entity_id']);
                $this->saveOrderqueued($order['increment_id']);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public function saveOrderqueued($orderId){
//        $orderdetails = $this->_modelOrder->load($entityid);
        $orderdetails = $this->orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
        $orderdetails->setQueued("1");
//unable to save 
        $orderdetails->save();
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There was some issue in my database but we can save order in foreach like this

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order $orderResourceModel
) {
    $this->orderResourceModel = $orderResourceModel;
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
}

public function execute()
{
   $this->saveOrderqueued($order['entity_id']);
}
public function saveOrderqueued($orderId){
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
        $order->setQueued(1);
        $this->orderResourceModel->save($order);
    }
```